# Draw a circle representing remaining time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, draw, geometry

I want to draw a circle in my application.

Actually, there is a timer for 20 seconds and I have to draw a circle with red and green colors, according to the remaining time.

Please help me if you have code or similar examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a circle you may use (in your `drawRect` method)

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
CGContextBeginPath (context);

CGContextAddArc (context, CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, RADIUS, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
CGContextDrawPath (context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

To simulate the timer you may consider use `CGContextAddLineToPoint` and `CGContextMoveToPoint` to draw lines and `CGContextSetFillColor` to change the current fill color.

Check [CGContext Reference](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html&ei=lH5nTofeHejl4QTCqNDFDA&usg=AFQjCNEL6_EXLwjPTgWUPgZdI08Ik1xvmg&sig2=odfhfAeOZrTHzNevPC99Pg)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got an example project of draw circle.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but I hope it helps: You probably want to look at the documentation for the following functions:

- CGContextAddArc
- CGContextAddArcToPoint
- CGContextFillEllipseInRect
- CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect

And a Google search for those functions will probably find some useful sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I know [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) on GitHub has that ability. I have used it before and it is very easy to implement.